# How to add all colums in a datagrid to SQL Server 2008 database

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2008

I am using a datagridview and added columns to it ...and accordingly with textboxes I add data to the datagridview.. this a list of products a customer wants to buy it ..the first column is `CustCode, ItemCode, Date` and `Quantity` ..these are the 4 columns and I add many rows..

Say I inserted 5 rows to the datagridview .... I now want to add all the data in the datagridview to a SQL Server 2008 database ....can someone write the whole code? I'm really confused, this code I have doesn't seem to work ... gives an error ..null parameter

```
SqlConnection con = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection();
con = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection();
con.ConnectionString = "Data Source=rex;Initial Catalog=Project DB 1;Integrated Security=True";

con.Open();
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();

for (int i = 0; i <= dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
{
    String insertData = "INSERT INTO SalesTable(CustCode,ItemCode,Date,Quantity) " + 
                        "VALUES (@CustCode,@ItemCode,@Date,@Quantity)";

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(insertData, con);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CustCode", dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ItemCode", dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date", dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Quantity", dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value);

    da.InsertCommand = cmd;
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
con.Close();
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly your question then you have one or more of your grid cells that doesn't contains a value and thus you get a null parameter- To insert a null inside the database you need to pass (as value for the parameter) the `DBNull.Value`

So your code could be rewritten as

```
using(SqlConnection con = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection("Data Source=rex;Initial Catalog=Project DB 1;Integrated Security=True"))
{
    con.Open();
    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
    {
        if(!row.IsNewRow)
        {
            String insertData = "INSERT INTO SalesTable(CustCode,ItemCode,Date,Quantity) " + 
                                "VALUES (@CustCode,@ItemCode,@Date,@Quantity)";

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(insertData, con);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CustCode", row.Cells[0].Value ?? DbNull.Value);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ItemCode", row.Cells[1].Value ?? DBNull.Value);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date", row.Cells[2].Value ?? DBNull.Value);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Quantity", row.Cells[3].Value ?? DBNUll.Value);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
}
```

I have used the [C# Null Coalescing operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx) to test if the value of one of your cells is null.
Also I have removed the useless DataAdapter and fixed the creation, initialization and disposing of the connection

See also [IsNewRow Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewrow.isnewrow.aspx) from the DataGridViewRow

Comment: @ Steve .. the code works ..but ...if i insert 4 rows .. 5 get inserted into the database ...the 5th one inserts a complete null row.... plz help

Comment: the extra row was because of the datagrid option of allowUserToAddRow option .. after i set it to false it gives a error (Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection).. please help

Comment: So, you have a row templato to add new rows. In this case you need to avoid to add this row to the database. Reload the page and check if the update works

Comment: hey Steve ..is there any way i can contact u for more help ?