# Deprecated: mysql_connect(): The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, mysqli

I am new to PHP and I'm trying to connect to my database with the help of some youtube videos but I get this error

> Deprecated: mysql_connect(): The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead in C:\wamp\www\db.php on line 7

Comment: You have to use [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) instead of mysql

Comment: Search for some newer videos!

Comment: The _warning_ is clear enough. See the PHP manual for `mysql_*()`and notice that big red box at the top of the page?

Comment: The error is obvious; do what it says. Wamp needs to update their demo files.

Answer (score 5):

The problem stems from [**Wampserver**](http://www.wampserver.com/en/)'s demo SQL files which include `mysql_*` based functions code.

*Sidenote:* They really should make a note of that or update their demo files to include test files containing `mysqli_` and/or PDO code to leave out the confusion, since the version of PHP that comes with it is 5.5.12, which would only make sense.

I myself have recently installed Wamp in one my machines a few weeks ago and was faced with the very same issue, yet I quickly remedied the situation by simply changing all instances of `mysql_` to `mysqli_` and setting the DB connection variable as the first parameter.

For example and taken from **http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-connect.php**

```
$result = mysqli_query($link, $query); // $link being the connection variable
```

This is what their demo SQL code looks like:

```
<?php 
$link = mysql_connect('hostname','dbuser','dbpassword'); 
if (!$link) { 
    die('Could not connect to MySQL: ' . mysql_error()); 
} 
echo 'Connection OK'; mysql_close($link); 
?>
```

Change it to the following as an example and changing the proper code for your own DB:

```
<?php 
$link = mysqli_connect('hostname','dbuser','dbpassword','db_name'); 
if (!$link) { 
    die('Could not connect to MySQL: ' . mysqli_error($link)); 
} 
echo 'Connection OK'; mysqli_close($link); 
?>
```

For more information on `mysqli_` and PDO, visit the following pages:

- **http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php**
- **http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php**

Additional links:

- [**`mysqli_*` with prepared statements**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)
- [**PDO with prepared statements**](http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements).

which are much better and safer to use when getting into database work.

Comment: @user2308205 You asked quite a few questions and have not accepted any of them. This one for example http://stackoverflow.com/q/16505715/ where the answer given resolved the problem (*" Done ...its works .. thanks alot bro .. :D –  user2308205 May 12 '13 at 10:07 "*). You need to accept answers **including mine here**. If you don't, then others may not want to help you again, including myself. Your questions may eventually get flagged and we wouldn't want that.

Answer (score 1):

***Deprecated: mysql_connect(): The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead in C:\wamp\www\gazal156\system\database\mysql.php on line 6***

1. I m use opencart 1.5.6 but run open cart site then show error.
2. Error in the simple solution.

**../system/database/mysql.php**

Top **add** line after

error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_DEPRECATED);

and save

Comment: This answer is very difficult to understand and doesn't really answer the question (you just suggest hiding `DEPRECATED` errors).